# Windows manager like mesh.com

Tags: c#, silverlight, mesh

I would like to create a basic webdesktop in silverlight 4.

How can I do a windows manager ?
I want to move, resize, minimized, maximized each windows like http://mesh.com...

Does it exist something to create easily a windows manager ?

Do I have to create everything from scratch ?
How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a desktop-like environment inside of Silverlight is definitely possible (there are examples out there) but it is not something that is included in the framework. You will need to build each of these features yourself or use a third party library.

You might want to look at projects such as the [C64 emulator](http://silverlightc64.codeplex.com/)

Are you looking to do something similar to [this Vectorlight sample](http://www.vectorlight.net/demos/silverlight_controls_demo.aspx)?

Also, take a look at [this](http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/silverlight-simulate-a-windows-desktop-application-part-1) blog post about simulating a windows desktop in Silverlight.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will etudiate your links. The vectorlight sample seems great